# How to retrieve multiple list of data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been searching for different examples but unable to find proper solution for my firebase nodes. I have 3 nodes 1 for Question ,Second node contains Answers of questions and 3rd node contains Comments on that Answer.!

How I will be Able to perform query using firebase 
I've been searching for different examples but unable to find proper solution for my fire base tables. I have 3 nodes

1. Questions
2. Answers
3. Comments on Answers

How I will be Able to perform query using firebase (Join based Concept Implementation)

```
mdatabaseReference.child("Answer").equalTo(QID);
```

how I will be able to get Answers of specific Question and Comments on that Answers.!

here is My JSON

```
    {
      "Answer" : {

        "f40357b1-d1f5-4b7a-98ec-54d9e7b2e518" : {

          "dateTime" : "16 Mar 2017 15:30:29",
          "professorAnswer" : "Hezbollah is an Islamist religious organization founded in 1985 and based in Lebanon. It follows Shi'Islam (also called Shi'ite Islam), the second largest denomination of Islam. Shi'a Muslims follow the teachings of the prophet Muhammad, a direct descendant of Isma'il (the first son of Ibrahim/Abraham).Contd.!",
          "professorId" : "7ceef713-eb59-4db4-a8d2-21d5a01eedfc",
          "questionId" : "fd2a34a0-e7d9-4b2c-8192-59705df827c2"
        }
      },

      "comment" : {
        "29192e3a-a013-4fcc-9859-1f5cc62464cb" : {
          "commentText" : "ORGANIZATION hezbollah bases on the bible but their goals is to save people in pagans work!",
          "dateTime" : "16 Mar 2017 15:30:52",
 "AnswerId" : "f40357b1-d1f5-4b7a-98ec-54d9e7b2e518"
          "questionId" : "fd2a34a0-e7d9-4b2c-8192-59705df827c2",
          "userId" : "bXCeW6jfidbHuMCCCMkDGWcGZRS2"
        }
      },



 "questions" : {

    "41c454a8-fab6-4e41-9093-b1120ffd1be0" : {
      "description" : "I know they're a Islamic organization but where are they based? What are their goals?",
      "idQuestion" : "fd2a34a0-e7d9-4b2c-8192-59705df827c2",
      "time" : "16 Mar 2017 15:30:12",
      "title" : "What are the aims of the religious organization Hezbollah?",
      "user_id" : "bXCeW6jfidbHuMCCCMkDGWcGZRS2",

    }
  },



 "user" : {

    "13bd37e5-fc87-4468-a89e-7cb4ecaab05f" : {

      "email" : "email@gmail.com ",
      "user_id" : "bXCeW6jfidbHuMCCCMkDGWcGZRS2"
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to filter those events... like for example, using `.orderByChild("Answer").equalTo(QID)` maybe it's wrong query but it is just for concept to get just the Answers for a given Question ID  and then populate my List with it.

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure in words, share a representative snippet of the JSON. You can get this by clicking Export JSON in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/).

Comment: waiting for your reply.! @ Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is to get every data separately, I don't know perfectly how your data are organized but this may be an appropriate solution:

```
// Gets the Question with id = QID
mdatabaseReference.child("Questions").child(QID);

// Gets the Answers for that question
mdatabaseReference.child("Answers").child(QID).once("value", function(answers) {

    // For every Answer gets the comments
    for(var answerID in answers) mdatabaseReference.child("Comments").child(QID).child(answerID);
});
```

**EDIT:** To use Firebase efficently you should structure your data depending on how you want to retrieve them. If you want to get all the answers for a given question I suggest you to use this data structure:

```
{
    "Answers": {
        "questionID": {
            "answerID": {
                "dateTime" : "16 Mar 2017 15:30:29",
                "professorAnswer" : "Hezbollah is an Islamist religious...,
                "professorID" : "...",
                "questionID" : "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so that you can get your data for a given questionID this way:

```
mdatabaseReference.child("Answer").child(questionID).once('value', function(answers) {
    // answers contains all the answer for the question with ID == questionID
});
```

**NOTE:** You don't have tables in Firebase, everything is JSON Object

Comment: I want to knw is there any Concept of join in Fire base .? where 1 only run query once and it show me answers and comments of specific question.?

Comment: There's no concept of join, it is good practice to get pieces of data separately and to organize your data depending on how you want to retrieve them. If you really want to get Answers and Comment you can put your comments as a child of the Answer, but I suggest you to try fetching your data separately, it is performant and is the right way to do it in Firebase :) This [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) is really usefull

Comment: but i dnt think so its good practice what if size of data get huge.?
then it will load every tables data and then comparing that data this thing will make my app slower.?

Comment: With this approach, you only fetch the data you need. For example, if you have 2000 questions you'll only get the question with `id == QID`.  It really depends on how you structure your data, I've updated my answer with an example of a good data structure for your problem. Let me know if you have more questions ;)

Comment: Tell me one thing.?

Comment: I don't get your question :)

Comment: Comments should be used to discuss the question and its answers. This doesn't seem to be related to the question, so you should accept this answer if solved your issue and write another question for this :)

Comment: I'm here if you have any doubts about this answer :)

Comment: Now have a look at my Data Structure.@ Devid Farinelli

Comment: That's nice @AtifAbbAsi! I've updated my answer, let me know what do you think about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There In No Concept of Joins In fireBase.Its noSql ..All you need to do is Query On According to Question Id and then in answer id check for question id..and same thing goes for comments it will be a nested EventBased search.!